# Using GWTQuery to call Bootstrap JS collapse method

Tags: gwt, gwtquery, gwtbootstrap3

I want to replicate this jQuery call in gQuery to open all closed Accordion panels at once:

```
$('.panel-collapse:not(".in")').collapse('show');
```

I have tested this on my app and it works, however I am unable to successfully implement the same logic using gQuery to call the JavaScript collapse method:

```
@Override
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
  GQuery.$(".panel-collapse").not(".in").trigger("collapse", "show");
}
```

**What is the correct way to call JavaScript methods from gQuery?**

Further Info - I have successfully tested this gQuery code in my onClick method to add a test class to the affected divs - so I am certain the selector part of the above query works:

```
GQuery.$(".panel-collapse").not(".in, .MENU").addClass("test");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why you can't use `collapse` with GQuery

IIRC `collapse()` is not a jQuery API method. Maybe you're using Bootstrap JS, or some jQuery plugin that provides this functionality, but it's not one of the jQuery API methods and thus it's not provided by GQuery.

#### Why `trigger` wouldn't work either

GQuery, or GwtQuery, is not a wrapper for jQuery, but a full Java implementation of the jQuery API.
What this means is that, when you do something like this:

```
GQuery.$(".panel-collapse").not(".in").slideToggle();
```

You're **not** invoking jQuery's `$()`, `not()`, or `slideToggle()`; you are using a Java library to achieve the same result.
That's the reason why trying something like `trigger("slideToggle")` won't work: because a) `slideToggle()` is not an event, but a function; and b) GQuery doesn't make use of jQuery's JS functions.

#### Solution with GQuery

You can achieve the same "accordion" effect using the `slideUp()`, `slideDown()` and `slideToggle()` <strike>functions</strike> methods. To open all the collapsed elements, just calling `slideDown()` on them should work:

```
GQuery.$(".panel-collapse").not(".in").slideDown();
```

For full accordion effect, combine those with the `toggleClass()` and `removeClass()` methods to mark which elements are open / closed so you know which ones to toggle when clicked.

#### Solution with native `collapse()`

Now, if you don't mind the advice... GQuery is great, but the animations are far from being as smooth as in native jQuery. I guess the same happens with Bootstrap.
If you can (and I can't see a reason why you couldn't), just use JSNI to make a native call to `collapse()` like this:

```
private native void collapseAll() /*-{
    $wnd.$('.panel-collapse:not(".in")').collapse('show');
}-*/;
```

This requires that you load jQuery (or Bootstrap) in your page, but since you said that invoking `collapse()` in plain JS worked, I guess that's your case.

Comment: `$wnd.$` needs that you load jQuery in your app. The goal of GQuery is not having to use that external library, but consume only what you need from GQuery

Comment: @ManoloCarrascoMoñino Yes, exactly. However, OP already said that a plain JS call to `collapse()` worked for them, so I took for granted that they already had jQuery loaded in their app. I'll edit my answer to make that clear. And don't get me wrong: your library is great! I really enjoyed your [GWT.Create 2015 presentation](http://gwtquery.github.io/gwt.create-slides/gwtcreate2015/gwtcreate2015.html), it really shows the potential of GQuery and I learned some useful examples. In my experience, though, native jQuery is smoother and the way to go _if you already use jQuery in your pages_.